# MySQL in-MEMORY table is full. How can I let it use more memory?

Tags: mysql

I get a message like `The table 'x' is full`, where `x` is a table using the MEMORY storage engine. I have more system memory available. How do I let this table actually use more memory? I raised `max_heap_table_size`, but the table is apparently still "full".

Answer (score 1):

You must re-create or alter the table to raise the table's memory limit. From the [manual page for `max_heap_table_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size):

> Setting this variable has no effect on any existing MEMORY table, unless the table is re-created with a statement such as [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) or altered with [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) or [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html).

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `x` ADD COLUMN `dummy` INT;
ALTER TABLE `x` DROP COLUMN `dummy`;
```

Look for a change in `Max_data_length` (in the result of `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'x'\G`) after running these `ALTER` statements.